# Why do I get this warning while reading Excel file with tFileInputExcel with Talend

Tags: excel, talend

My job worked like expected but I didn't understood Why do I get this warning while reading Excel file with tFileInputExcel with Talend ?

```
Warning:  Cannot read name ranges for LOCAL_DATE_SEPARATOR - setting to empty
Warning:  Cannot read name ranges for LOCAL_DAY_FORMAT - setting to empty
Warning:  Cannot read name ranges for LOCAL_HOUR_FORMAT - setting to empty
Warning:  Cannot read name ranges for LOCAL_MINUTE_FORMAT - setting to empty
Warning:  Cannot read name ranges for LOCAL_MONTH_FORMAT - setting to empty
Warning:  Cannot read name ranges for LOCAL_MYSQL_DATE_FORMAT - setting to empty
Warning:  Cannot read name ranges for LOCAL_SECOND_FORMAT - setting to empty
Warning:  Cannot read name ranges for LOCAL_TIME_SEPARATOR - setting to empty
Warning:  Cannot read name ranges for LOCAL_YEAR_FORMAT - setting to empty
```

[image]

Comment: try using new, clean spreadsheet.  Paste your data into the spreadsheet using the values only option, so that no formulas are carried over.  Load using this new clean spreadsheet.  My guess is that one of your cells i accessing a named range in another worksheet.  i cannot reproduce.

Comment: when I past my data in a new clean spreadsheet, I don't got that warning. Thank u ELaRoche
But the problem is that my excel file contains many sheets, I'm working now just with one sheet and I can't past the data that I want every time in a new spreadsheet

Comment: if you are sure the output if not affected then I would simply treat the warnings as info and ignore them.

Answer (score 1):

In Excel, go to Formula -> Name Manager (or Ctrl + F3) and then delete all the named ranges that don’t refer to anything.

Or use them somewhere in the workbook, either in formulas or charts.

Comment: The problem is that my Name Manager is empty !